# Read the response header when the status is 302 in Angular

Tags: angular, ajax, angular-httpclient, http-redirect, angular-httpclient-interceptors

How can I read the response header of `XHR` call by `$http` in Angular (v8+) as its status is 302 and it is redirected by browser? 
In my case as the redirect url has a different origin, I only get an Unknown error from the code below:

```
return this.http.get('/oauth2/authorization/keycloak').pipe(
        map(res => {
          // never called
          console.log(res);
          return res;
        }),
        tap( res => {
          // never called
          console.log(res);
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          // prints "Unknown Error"
          console.log(err);
          return err;
        })
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor. You will need to check HttpResponse [https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse].

Comment: The second page is not found!

Comment: It won't help, no matter if your in a interceptor or not, in this situation you can't have access to the first's request's header